# How to identify the last occurrence in a column of date format?

Tags: julia

I have a dataset containing information of some purchases starting on `03/01/2018 03:00` and ending on  `25/04/2022 15:00`. There's no pattern between dates and times of purchase occurrences. For instance, there's no purchase happening on `04/01/2018 05:00` or `04/01/2018 15:00`, etc. For each day, I am trying to find the latest time in which a purchase has happened.

For example, based on the following dataset, is it possible to have a dictionary that as a key stores dates and as a value the latest price of the purchase?

```
"03/01/2018" => 9.3
"04/01/2018" => 5.4
"03/01/2019" => 7.6
.... all the way to 25/04/2022 15:00
```

[image]

Comment: For future reference: when asking questions, having a **runnable**, **copy-pasteble** example is important to get quick and quality answers.

Comment: Just as I wrote in the answer, there are more ways to solve this. And I expected an `InMemoryDatasets` answer (for many reasons). My heart goes out to the people behind `InMemoryDatasets` which are trying so hard to gain acceptance. Sometimes they promote themselves too much. But Julia community likes diversity and good devs - this is what makes it so Zen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DataFrames` package:

```
using DataFrames
using Dates
using IterTools
using Random

# create test df
Random.seed!(123)

df = DataFrame(ts = Iterators.take(Iterators.filter(x-> 9 ≤ hour(x) ≤ 18, 
  repeatedly(
    ()->rand(DateTime(2018,1,3):Millisecond(1):DateTime(2018,1,10)))
  ),10) |> collect)
df.price = rand(100.0:110.0, nrow(df))
df.sell = df.price .+ 5*randn(nrow(df))
sort!(df)

# process test df
df.day = Dates.date2epochdays.(Date.(df.ts))
df.usethis = vcat(df.day[1:end-1] .!= df.day[2:end], false)
select(df[df.usethis, :], 
  :day => ByRow(Dates.epochdays2date) => :day, :price)
```

The last expression returns:

```
5×2 DataFrame
 Row │ day         price   
     │ Date        Float64 
─────┼─────────────────────
   1 │ 2018-01-03    100.0
   2 │ 2018-01-04    103.0
   3 │ 2018-01-05    103.0
   4 │ 2018-01-06    107.0
   5 │ 2018-01-07    106.0
```

for `df`:

```
10×5 DataFrame
 Row │ ts                       price    sell      day     usethis 
     │ DateTime                 Float64  Float64   Int64   Bool    
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 2018-01-03T17:10:13.346    100.0  100.161   737062     true
   2 │ 2018-01-04T15:18:53.364    103.0  100.236   737063     true
   3 │ 2018-01-05T12:55:30.312    102.0  102.621   737064    false
   4 │ 2018-01-05T15:59:58.184    101.0   95.0074  737064    false
   5 │ 2018-01-05T17:37:07.789    103.0   98.6223  737064     true
   6 │ 2018-01-06T15:33:50.104    101.0   99.4635  737065    false
   7 │ 2018-01-06T16:18:40.614    100.0  112.788   737065    false
   8 │ 2018-01-06T16:32:07.132    107.0  105.55    737065     true
   9 │ 2018-01-07T15:37:50.536    106.0  107.161   737066     true
  10 │ 2018-01-09T12:48:12.069    105.0  101.265   737068    false
```

But there are many ways to solve this. And I'm waiting to see other options.

Answer (score 3):

Using `InMemoryDatasets` package:

```
ds=Dataset(df)
setformat!(ds,:date=>yearmonthday) # no data modification - lazy format
unique(ds,:date,keep=:last,mapformats=true)
```

Comment: I'ven't heard about `InMemoryDatasets`, but this is a very cool answer.